# in openpyxl how to find the max_column number in a particular row

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

We know that `sheet.max_column()` gives the maximum column number of the whole Excel file. But my question is how to find the maximum column number in a particular row?

Suppose there is a saved Excel file which is not empty and I want to know 3rd row's max column number of that Excel file. So how can I find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved with a simple for loop and if statement. I checked whether it is empty or not, then if it is empty I assigned a value. 'A' is the column, you can change it as you wish. Here is what I do:

```
 workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('RankingInfo.xlsx')
 sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
 for i in range(1,20000):
   if sheet['A'+str(i)].value == None:
      sheet['A'+str(i)] = isbn
  workbook.save('RankingInfo.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help me. i also think that way. but i find any keyword to do this work.